# making visible and invisible a button

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, show-hide

So my problem is the following ive made 2 fucntion which the objective is to return if a edittext has something writen or not, if it has i want it to make a button visible if not i want the buton to stay invisible. But this isnt working im gona show all my code

functions, this are the functions ive made:

```
private boolean checkEditText(EditText edit) {
return edit.getText().length() == 0;
}



 void updateButtonState() {
if(checkEditText(inputdtestab) && checkEditText(quantidade))
{
inputdtestab.setError("yipikaei");
quantidade.setError("mudfukkerrr");
}
else{
     // Create button
Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.visible);

    }
 }
```

this dont work and i think the reason is because it doesnt run the else part of the code, because i tried creating a button and when i click on it make the button appear and it works fine. But doing as i want, it doesnt work.

All code:

```
 @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "CutPasteId" })
public class Newlin_ProductActivity extends Activity{

 /** WebServices */
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 EditText inputdtestab;
  EditText inputdata;
  EditText inputhora;
 EditText quantidade;
 EditText etDate;
 Button change_date;

 String id2;
 String data;
 String data2;

   int Date_Dialog_ID=0;

  int cDay,cMonth,cYear; // this is the instances of the current date
 Calendar cDate;
  int sDay,sMonth,sYear; // this is the instances of the entered date




  // url to create new product
  private static String url_create_product =       "http://10.0.2.2/webprojecto4/inserir_lin_doc.php";

 // JSON Node names
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
  private static final String TAG_ID = "id";

 private static final String DATA = "dt";
 private static final String DATA2 = "dt2";

 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.add_linha);


 Intent i = getIntent(); 
 id2 = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
 data = i.getStringExtra(DATA);
 data2 = i.getStringExtra(DATA2);



 /** WebServices */
 inputdtestab= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editestab);
 inputdata = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editdata);
 inputhora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edithora);
 quantidade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editquantidade);

 inputhora.setText(hr);


 // Create button
Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

 // button click event
btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // creating new product in background thread
    new CreateNewProduct().execute();
}
 });


  updateButtonState();

  }

 //restriçoes ver
private boolean checkEditText(EditText edit) {
return edit.getText().length() == 0;
}



 void updateButtonState() {
if(checkEditText(inputdtestab) && checkEditText(quantidade))
{
inputdtestab.setError("yipikaei");
quantidade.setError("mudfukkerrr");
}
else{
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.visible);

    }
 } 






  private OnDateSetListener onDateSet=new OnDateSetListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, 
  int dayOfMonth) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 System.out.println("2");
 sYear=year;
 sMonth=monthOfYear;
  sDay=dayOfMonth;
 updateDateDisplay(sYear,sMonth,sDay);
 }
 };




/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
 class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

/**
 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
 * */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Newlin_ProductActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Creating product
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    String id_estab = inputdtestab.getText().toString();
    String quantidades = quantidade.getText().toString();
    String data = inputdata.getText().toString();
    String hr = inputhora.getText().toString();





    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_cab_doc", id2));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num_lin", ""));//ir buscar criar
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_produto", "00000"));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_tipo_produto", "00"));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_estab", id_estab));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantidade", quantidades));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dt", data));
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hr", hr));


    // getting JSON Object
    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
            "POST", params);

    // check log cat fro response
    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    // check for success tag
    try {
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // successfully created product
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Linhas_pesagem.class);
            i.putExtra(TAG_ID, id2);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);

            // closing this screen
            finish();
        } else {
            // failed to create product
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Linhas_pesagem.class);
            i.putExtra(TAG_ID, id2);

            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
}

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"So my problem is the following ive made 2 fucntion which the objective is to return if a edittext has something writen or not, if it has i want it to make a button visible if not i want the buton to stay invisible. But this isnt working im gona show all my code."

So basically you want to display the button if input value is provided in your EditText views. And hide the button otherwise.

Edit your `updateButtonState()` method as follows:

```
void updateButtonState() {
    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    if(checkEditText(inputdtestab) && checkEditText(quantidade)) {
        inputdtestab.setError("yipikaei");
        quantidade.setError("mudfukkerrr");

        // ==========================================
        // make the button invisible.
        btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // or use View.GONE
    } else {

        // ==========================================
        // make button visible.
        // use the method "setVisibility", not "setViewVisibility"
        // and "VISIBLE" in "View.VISIBLE" is in full cap:
        btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

To make the button invisible, write `btnCreateProduct.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`.

If you would like the button to take up the space when it is not visible, you can use `View.GONE` instead of `View.INVISIBLE`.

## UPDATE

To display the button immediately when the `EditText`s are filled in, you have to listen to the change of the text of the `EditText`s. First you implement the [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

```
private TextWatcher myTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {}
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {}

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    // invoke the following method here:
    updateButtonState();
  }
};
```

and then add the watcher as the listener for both of your `EditText`s.

```
inputdtestab.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
quantidade.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

Comment: @user3626801 What do you mean? `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` does not hide the button?

Comment: Does `button2` exist in the layout of `Newlin_ProductActivity`? What exceptions are you getting, if any?

Comment: the button is set invisible in the xml layout and  if the edittexts are not empty i want to make the button visible. i did has y shown but it doesnt work and doesnt show any errors

Comment: So you want the button to appear immediately when the two `EditText`s are filed in?

Comment: i dont know what the problem is because the code makes sence and its easy to understand, but i cant find the reason for not working. i really think that it doesnt enter in the else cycle

Comment: You need to call `updateButtonState()` when the text of your `EditText`s is changed. Please see my update.

Comment: sorry coud y edit my functions iam a little confused

Answer (score 0):

`setViewVisibility` means that you need to define the id of the view. Instead, use:

```
yourButton.setVisibility( View.(GONE, HIDDEN, VISIBLE, ...))
```

Comment: already done that but it doesnt work. When i run the project and i fill the edittexts the button doesnt apear